# Java SQL Connection isolation

Tags: java, sql

How does java.sql.Connection class grant isolation levels? I mean:

Let's think on the most restrictive case, using

```
connection.setTransactionLevel(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE);
...
operation on table A;
...
...
operation on table B;
...
connection.commit();
```

During all this time, what tables are locked to grant serialization of data? table A? table B? all database?

If it locks all database, it means no other connection can do anything, even if this first connection is not gonna work on other tables?

If it does not, how can java realize it's gonna require table A and table B?

I am concerned about what performance impact it can have in my application, if I just need to lock same tables, not the whole database.

Comment: what code are you performing that would cause a whole table lock?

Comment: Just read/writes on tables A/B. Why wouldnt it lock it? isnt that what TRANSACTION_SERIALIZE does? "A constant indicating that dirty reads, non-repeatable reads and phantom reads are prevented."

Comment: I guess it may depend on the DB, but IIRC postgres and mysql would do row locks - table locks would be horrendously expensive

Comment: Could you post a link with documentation over that please? Could not find anything related

Comment: maybe this helps https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking.html - scary stuff

Comment: java.sql.Connection  is an interface. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs45/classdocs/java.sql.Connection.html You should look at specific DB provider docs.

Comment: @ScaryWombat thank you, that helped me a lot!